# Joomla User Login needs secret key - How to remove?

Tags: joomla, authentication, key

My Joomla Login Module asks for a **"Secret Key"**. *(Joomla Version 3.2.1)*

***This is confusing, was not necessary before. Can this be removed?***

[image: Extra field for a secred key]

This is my demo website:

- http://bierbrouwland.be/bier/

It's all about beer. Might be helpfull ;-)

*Thanks for the help!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Two factor authentication** is a new feature in Joomla 3.2.

If you have not set a *'Secret Key'* for a user:

- Go to Extensions > Plugin Manager
- Set the Select Type filter to twofactorauth
- You'll see two plugins enabled - Google and Yobikey - change their status to Disabled. A red X icon will show up
- Clear the Joomla Cache

If you have actually set a key to your admin user, then there is no way out of it other than to go back to your last backup file.

Known bugs:

- There was a bug Joomla 3.2, and this is fixed in Joomla v3.2.1
- There is also a bug in the Gangry-framework with Joomla v3.2.1 (http://www.gantry-framework.org/) Which will be handeled by their development team.

You can now select in the plugin(s) to disable users (FrontEnd) from seeing the Secret Key but keep administrator login Secret Key.

Answer (score 2):

You have "Two factor authentication" enabled. Nicely explained on this video: [Joomla 3.2 - Two Factor Authentication](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbG6eehASW8)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even if the two factor authentication has been set for admin user, the plugin still can be disabled directly in the database, so you don't have to revert to backups. Nice and easy:

```
UPDATE jos_extensions SET enabled=0 WHERE name LIKE 'plg_twofactorauth_%';
```

Refresh the login page, et voila! :)

Answer (score 1):

in the Joomla "Search" type in twofactorauth right click the two that populate and select open in new tab for both.

Each tab will display two difference plugins enabled.

You will have a choice of Site Section for each,

You can choose (site frontend) (Administrator Backend) (both) So if you don't want your users to see it select, Administrator Backend, rather then disable it.

SO...

Site front end - Only Users will have a secret key
Administrator back end - Only Administrators will have a secret key
Both - Both users and admins will have a secret key field

Answer (score -1):

If your template is rockettheme

1.- In your template/css folder create a file called   rt_yourtemplatename-custom.css

2.- Add the following code:

```
 p#form-login-secretkey {
    display: none;
    }
```

3.- Done!